# How create a node with three protocol layers in OMNET++

Tags: omnet++, inet

i need to create two nodes which represents two devicews with three protocol layers (Physical, MAC and Application layer).

I am new on OMNET++. Hope to get help from you guys.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I think that this image answers your question:
[image: Protocol stack]
(Veins - the open source vehicular network simulation framework by Christoph Sommer, David Eckhoff, Alexander Brummer, Dominik S. Buse,
Florian Hagenauer, Stefan Joerer and Michele Segata)

Also the one in veins main page says it but maybe is not listing the layers as in the other picture: https://veins.car2x.org/documentation/veins-arch.png

So when we create a new "veins node" we basically are already implementing at least two of those layers. Just consider the Erlangen example, inside homonymous folder inside veins framework and check from there how it's done.

Comment: Thanks a lot. waiting for the paper or book. and thanks a lot again

Comment: I updated the main answer.